# 'The stream was not opened for writing.' exception issue

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, httprequest

The task is to update `.docx` file that is stored on SharePoint. For this reason I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/ package.

No data should be stored on the local drive, so I'm trying to work with `Stream`.
This is my code:

```
Stream docStream = await _httpClient!.GetStreamAsync(uri);

using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docStream, true))
{
   string docText = null;
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
   {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
   }

   Regex regexText = new Regex("OldText");
   docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "NewText");

   Stream outputDocStream = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create);

   return outputDocStream;
}
```

**Line 2** of my code gives the following exception:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackageException: 'The stream was not opened for writing.'
```

Can anyone advise how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient` returns a read-only stream, thus to make any changes to data in it the simplest solution would be to make a copy of that stream to a `MemoryStream`